# Replacement for mail alerts for query errors

Tags: error-logging

Up until now our web applications sent out a mail to alert us of errors. So if a query results in an error, a mail is sent out with the query and the error. Now we've had a situation where this resulted in thousands of mails. A few thousand mails in the course of a day is no problem, but when it's much more in less than an hour, problems arise. The whole story is a bit more complex.

I would like to know what alternatives we have. What methods do you use to report these errors? If you use a similar method, have you taken measures to prevent a situation like this?

Comment: What is making queries? Software? Emails? Either way, you could just log the errors to a database, and then if you want to review the errors, dish them up to an HTML page!

Comment: Example: a web application that submits a query, and a new column is missing on the production database. This results in an error, which is returned to the application. This error is then mailed to us. Another example is a connection error. The application cannot connect to the database, and then sends out an email to alert us about this. If we would log them in a database, that could become problematic.

Comment: Have it write to a log file, and check the log file then!